# Supervisor unrecognized service issue after install

Tags: python, ubuntu, supervisord

If I install supervisor from `apt-get` I get version 3.0b2-1 and if I run `sudo service supervisor status` I get `is running` (older beta version working fine)

A directory at `/etc/supervisor` is created with `supervisord.conf` file inside and empty dir `conf.d`

However, trying to install latest version (3.1.1) with pip or easy_install and running `service supervisor status` I get `supervisor: unrecognized service` (latest version not working)

No configuration files are created at `/etc` so I did `echo_supervisord_conf > /etc/supervisord.conf` as said at [docs](http://supervisord.org/installing.html).

I can't run service start/stop/restart/status... And I don't know if supervisor will actually work. Any ideas here?

Note: I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04 x64 machine.

Comment: You might need to run `supervisorctl reread` to read new configs.

Comment: I am having the same issue, with an AWS (Ubuntu 14.04) instance for which I have the root password. Running `supervisorctl reread` does not resolve. I've tried installing both with `sudo pip install supervisor` and `sudo apt-get install supervisor`.

Comment: So what did you both end up doing?  I need to install supervisor inside of a virtualenv, but I want it to respond to sudo service supervisor commands.

Comment: @Raj I've added an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I finally did is to actually work with the `apt-get` installation. No issues found with it.

Comment: I did not get it!!   How did you solve the problem ??

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend going the route of adding an upstart service as shown [here](https://serverfault.com/a/115259/255593).

Once you've created the upstart conf file, you can then just do:

```
sudo start supervisord
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue due to `/etc/init.d/supervisord` lacking executable mode.

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/supervisord
```

Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

For others that stumbled upon this thread, I had the same issue however my file structure was wrong.

My structure was `/etc/init.d/supervisor/supervisord`.

This does not work. You need to have the `supervisord` file inside of `init.d` like so: `/etc/init.d/supervisord`.