# Supervisor unrecognized service when installed in virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, supervisord

I wanted to install supervisor via pip only in my virtualenv environment. So I created a new virtualenv (testenv) and ran the command

```
sudo pip install supervisor
```

This was possible of course, but now when I wanted to start it I get the error:

```
(testenv)daniel@daniel-ThinkPad-T530:~$ sudo service supervisor start
supervisord: unrecognized service
```

Why can't I run supervisor if I install it with pip in my virtualenv?

Comment: Solved: I'll install supervisor via apt as normal. It just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run supervisor via upstart as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27536229/264567).